# How to Get Range Values on a comboBox with a Database Data on C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, combobox

Not sure if my question above was written correctly, if not, I apologize.

I have a database of students that have different grades on different class projects, assignments, etc.  My duty is that when I select an item from my comboBox, it should populate the students within the selected range. For example, the text on the comboBox reads the following:

- From 0 to 10
- From 11 to 20
- From 21 to 30
- From 31 to 40

If I select `From 11 to 20`, I should get the students that received grades from `11 to 20`.
Now, this is a school assignment so I must use these texts; I cannot change them to 0, 10, 20, etc.

I have my connection to my database on Access.  I have another comboBox that is much simpler, meaning, the comboBox items reads: Assignment 1, Assignment 2, etc, and that connection works.  My issue is trying to tell C# that what I have selected, translated to the range within the text.  Here is my code for that button:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String homeWork = cboHomeWork.Text; //This works fine and it filters correctly
   String range = cboRangeGrades.Text; //This will return an error because the text is complexed

}

     String sqlFilter = String.Format("Select * from activities where HomeWork = '{0}' and range = '{1}' ", homeWork, range);

getStudents(sqlFilter); //Calling the SQL instructions from above
```

Any suggestions on what would be the correct way to get that range data from the database using these ranges?

I tried using an `if` statement too:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String homeWork = cboHomeWork.Text; //This works fine and it filters correctly
    String range = cboRangeGrades.Text; //This will return an error because the text is complexed

    if (cboRangeGrades.Text == "From 0 to 10")
    {
      //But this will return an error saying that the criteria is not correct. 
      range = String sqlFilter = String.Format("Select * from activities where range = 10");
      //To my understanding, that Query is not written correctly even though on Access it works.
    }

}
    
   String sqlFilter = String.Format("Select * from activities where HomeWork = '{0}' and range = '{1}' ", homeWork, range);
    
   getStudents(sqlFilter); //Calling the SQL instructions from above
```

Thanks!

Comment: The second one should work but you placed again the same text for sqlfilter in the last. You have multiple options for fetching data. But to do that we need more details. can you update your question with more details. Details like what these variable values contains, gow you have it in database and how you want to display in the UI would be helpful.

Comment: How do you store range values in your database?

Comment: @JackLe - The database is provided.  All I had to do was connect to it, create a UI software with comboBox and Data Grid View where I will populate the information.  This Data Grid View has the columns: `Date, Student, Homework, Grades`, which are the same as in the Access Database.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida - I will give it a try just like you mentioned.  The connection of the database is live, and it works correctly.  On the database, I have the columns `Date, Student, Homework, Grades` and they will be pulled from the Database just like that to be shown on the UI.

Comment: @AdrianAcostaPR you didn't understand my question. If the [range] column is integer, you can use `BETWEEN value1 AND value2`

Comment: @JackLe ah, I apologize. They are integer, yes.

Comment: @AdrianAcostaPR you can do as I mentioned above or change your query to `[range] >= value1 and value2 <=[range]`. You can easily extract the numbers from the selected text (for example From 31 to 40), there are many different ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229072/discussion-between-adrianacostapr-and-jack-le).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Replace()`:

```cs
string homeWork = "Assignment 1";
string range = "From 11 To 20";
string criteria = range.Replace("From", "between").Replace("To", "and");
String sqlFilter = String.Format("select * from activities where HomeWork = '{0}' and grade {1}", homeWork, criteria);

Console.WriteLine(sqlFilter);
// select * from activities where HomeWork = 'Assignment 1' and Grade between 11 and 20
```